# How run the container with zsh (zshell) while starting the container using docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use zsh as a part of shell in the running docker container. The thing is, I am using the third part image, Therefore I cannot update the image file.

**zsh**

- zsh is already installed in my system.
- Path for my zsh is '/bin/zsh'

***The Solutions that I have tried is:***

- docker exec -it container_id /bin/zsh
- docker exec -it container_id zsh

**Exceptions While running above commands:**

- OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/zsh": stat /bin/zsh: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: Well, you *can* change an image, just write a Dockerfile based on this 3rd party image.

Comment: Using a command like `docker exec -it container_id /bin/zsh` means running an interactive shell within the container, executing `/bin/zsh` from inside the container. That's the point of containers, they're separated from your host. ZSH needs to be installed in it.

Comment: You are right, but is there any other way around where I don't really need to create the separate Dockerfile for the the third party image and start the zsh inside?

Comment: Yes but it will still involve creating a new image: you could run commands to install ZSH into the container (using `docker exec`, interactively or not) and then use [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) which will add a new layer to the image, saved with the desired name. This is handy for quick debugging but I'd really recommend using a Dockerfile if you're building something that'll live longer than 5 minutes.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Thank you so much for the help.